# How to make your page responsive to any viewport size react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have an image where you can click on one of the faces.

My problem is that when the browser window is bigger or smaller, the button does not change on Jesus's face and does not re-size automatically resize as well as the image and the text (they need to stay in the middle of the screen)

I need to have some kind of responsive function that can keep track of the resolution when the screen is bigger or smaller.

the red button should stay on Jesus whenever you resize the page and the image should resize

find here the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-shockley-84rvo5?file=/src/ButtonWelcomePage.js:871-960):

**Welcome button:**

```html
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
// import { COUNTER } from "./redux";
// import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Btn = styled.button`
display: inline-block;
/* background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.text}; */
background-color: red;
color: ${(props) => props.theme.body};
outline: none;
border: none;

font-size: ${(props) => props.theme.fontsm};
padding: 1.9rem 2.3rem; // change the size of the box
border-radius: 50px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
position: relative;
&:hover{
    transform: scale(0.9);
}

@media (max-width: 70em){
top: 30%;
}

@media (max-width: 64em){
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;

    &>*:last-child{
        width: 30%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 50em){

    &>*:last-child{
        width: 30%;
    }
}

`;

export default function ButtonWelcomePage() {
  // const selector = useSelector((state) => state);
  // const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div className="ButtonWelcomePage">
      <Btn>click</Btn>
      {/* <h1>Nr: {selector.counter}</h1> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**welcome page**

```html
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import LastSupper from "./LastSupper.svg";

import ButtonWelcomePage from "./ButtonWelcomePage";
// import Counter from '../Counter';

// import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Section = styled.div`
min-height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
/* background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.text}; */
background-color: black;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
position: relative;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 75%;
  height: 75vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  // background-color: lightblue; // we can change the color

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  @media (max-width: 70em) {
    width: 85%;
  }

  @media (max-width: 64em) {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;

    & > *:last-child {
      width: 80%;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 40em) {
    & > *:last-child {
      width: 90%;
    }
  }
`;
const Box = styled.div`
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
`;

const Box1 = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
`;

const WelcomePage = () => {
  return (
    <Section>
      <Box1>
        <ButtonWelcomePage>Box2</ButtonWelcomePage>
      </Box1>
      <Container>
        <Box>
          <img src={LastSupper} alt={LastSupper} height="550vh" />
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </Section>
  );
};

export default WelcomePage;
```

Comment: One way would be  calculating the image size and find the center of Jesus face where you can put your button on. And set the position of the button to `absolute` and use `top` and `left` properties.

Comment: hi thank you for you answer, use top and left properties to do what?

Comment: Set the position for the button.